# Json parse from Facebook events

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have had some trouble with fetching json from a groups events on facebook and then put them in a tableview to be used in a Appcelerator mobile app.

The idea is to have this as a calendar to show events for a club in a simple way.

I want to show the name of the event. The picture for that event and the date for the event.

All in a tablerow.

I have gotten to the part where i can get the Name and date for the events with this code:

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';

var    access_token='AAACEdEose0cBAAICGa4tFTcZAqCOGm2w9qPYGZBwNtJ1oZAcwaMAP2DDHZCN58cvVBZCHZADZAZBTPC8tTnpfQ7uGKI5j3SbMYcRmWquZCdPzhwZDZD';

var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/64306617564/events?&access_token=" + access_token ;
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
var json, data, row, name, start_time, id;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload: function() {
// Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    data = json.data[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:'60dp'
    });
  var  name = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:data.name,
        font:{
            fontSize:'18dp',
        fontWeight:'bold'
    },
    height:'auto',
    left:'50dp',
    top:'5dp',
    color:'#000',
    touchEnabled:true
    });



   var start_time = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'"' + data.start_time + '"',
    font:{
        fontSize:'13dp'
    },
    height:'auto',
    left:'15dp',
    bottom:'5dp',
    color:'#000',
    touchEnabled:true
    });


    row.add(name);
    row.add(start_time);
    tableData.push(row);
    }

table.setData(tableData);
},
onerror: function(e) {
Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
},
timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

But when i want the specific event to open in a new window when clicked i just get the event that lies last on the screen when i put this in a browser:

https://graph.facebook.com/64306617564/events?&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAOLAFWMKPmvgqEwap1ldnl7DeZBDKJC6YTZC4Goh6K5NHsvpOFmFQaGp1IekVsCxZCZCz3lwGpRcQG9ZBkcMrZAnLk4As8kgZDZD

And the access token expires REALLY fast. Any ideas how to make an access token that lasts longer?

Well,  the code i am using to open the window is:

```
table.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        // Create the new window with the link from the post
        var blogWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            title   : data.name,
            modal   : true,
            barColor: '#050505',
            backgroundColor: '#050505'              
        });
        var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.facebook.com/events/' + data.id});
        blogWindow.add(webView);

        // Create the close button to go in the left area of the navbar popup
        var close = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Close',
            style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.PLAIN
        });
        blogWindow.setLeftNavButton(close);

        // Handle the close event
        close.addEventListener('click',function() {
            blogWindow.close();
        });



        blogWindow.open();
    });
win.add(table);
win.open();
```

in my opinion that should open the event that is clicked on by parsing the ID from the row and putting it after the link.

Am i retarded or what is wrong?

It doesnt matter on which event i click it just open the last one all of the times.

And how can i get a thumbnail for the events?

Pls help........

Answer (score 0):

When you click on table to get value from **data** which is not available.You can achieve it using you custom variable try to put this line of code at your row creation where you add your row in array i.e.`row.data = data;` and on table click event get that object using this `alert(e.source.data);` and check it. Best luck